# Externalize application.properties of tasks or Jobs launched from SCDF

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow, configmap

I'm running a SCDF in openshift environment. I use SCDF to launch Batch jobs(spring.application.name=EmployeeBatchJob ) in the same environment. Now I need to externalize the application.properties of my EmployeeBatchJob , especially datasource password, So I don't maintain the passwords anywhere in my git repo.

I use ConfigMap to specify datasource for SCDF. And the batch application needs two datasources. So if I want to externalize my application.properties of my batch app, should I create a separate configMap only for batch app ? If so how to refer/access that configmap in the POD launched by SCDF. (Here I have externalize two datasources). What are all the properties required to refer that configmap?

**EmployeeBatchJob application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.source1.password = abcd
spring.datasource.source2.password = efgh

These two properties of application should be moved to configmap and read by the POD when deployed from SCDF as Job
```

I tried Cloud-config-map. But still I would be storing the password in git repo. So i'm looking for ways to store it in openshift environment and access it.

For a normal Spring boot application we can use ConfigMap and mount it as volume in the deployment configuration of the SpringBoot application. But I'm using SCDF to launch my batch application(EmployeeBatchJob).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To hold sensitive information such as passwords, I would actually create an Openshift [secret](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/secrets.html), better than a configmap, and just reference it anywhere you need to get its value from in the yamls.

Based on [Spring SCDF docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.1.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/), section "Part III. Getting Started", you can modify the Secrets in the `src/etc/kubernetes/scdf-secrets.yml`, remember to use base64 for passwords.

Comment: If I use a secret how could I refer it in SCDF POD configuration. As the POD launched by SCDF doesn't have separate deployment.yaml

Comment: any news o this? did it help?

Comment: Hi Javier, No the docs are specifc to SCDF POD for which I already have set up the secrets and config map. But I'm talking about the task application being launched from there. Those task/job pods couldn't access configmap info, where SCDF pod can. Because for I mounted config map as volume for scdf. But its not possible for Task/jobs being launched from SCDF.